# How to reassociate a database object with another one in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I'm having trouble phrasing this question, so consequently I'm also having trouble finding answers. Hopefully someone can help me word it better. Anyway, I can't find any standard procedures for managing the reassociation of a given database row with another row that may or may not already exist. For example, say we've got two models:

```
class Residence  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zipcode
end

...

class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :residences
end
```

Now say my data is screwed up and I want to change the zipcode of a residence. I can't just make a standard rails form for it because I don't want to change the zipcode itself (i.e., change zipcode with id=1 to 90210 instead of 90123), I want to reassociate the residence with a new zipcode that may or may not already be in the database.

I can think of a number of ways to do this, but it seems like something that one might always be looking to do with a many-to-one relationship, and I'd like to learn the "best practices" way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one responded and I've moved on already, I figured I'd share the technique that I decided on to handle this problem. Since what I needed to send back in the parameters array was an id (presumably something the end user never actually sees), the only clean way to do it was to use an AJAX call to the zipcodes table for a different zipcode ID. Effectively, the residence form included an arbitrarily-named input element that served to allow the user to enter a zipcode and select from a list that was returned. If he selected a zipcode from the list, it's ID was populated in a hidden field that was sent along with the form. If not, the zipcode was created (and validated) upon form submission and then its ID added to the params array as the zipcode_id field before calling `update_attributes()` on the residence object.

If anyone knows of a better way to do this, please share. This worked fine for me, though.